# Creating a pointer to an object without new keyword

Tags: c++

Is the following code the same as `ClassName* obj = new ClassName();`?

```
ClassName* obj;
obj = methodName();
```

I found it [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/):

```
GLFWwindow* window;
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: No, it is not. It's a compile time error in most instances. And when it isn't it's likely to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `obj = new ClassName();` is valid though.

Comment: Did you ,mean ClassName obj;
 obj = ClassName();

Comment: `glfwCreateWindow` is a function call.... You can't call constructors like you do functions.

Comment: as the current answer would be fine with it, I would suggest you to change `obj = ClassName();` to something like `obj = xyzCreateObjectOfClassName();` because currently you are comparing an orange with an (broken) apple. Would give you at least one downvote less ;)

Comment: What you assume is a `class` name is actually a *function name* that returns the object (presumably) after creating it with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GLFWwindow* window;
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
```

Look into the function `glfwCreateWindow`.  Most likely, the function either dynamically creates an instance of `GLFWwindow` or points to a statically declared instance.  Think of it as a similar function to `new`.

And to answer the title of your question, yes, you can assign a pointer to an object without using `new` or `malloc`:

```
static MyObject object;
MyObject *  myPointer;
myPointer = &object;
```